# Outlook Move to Folder very slow

Tags: ms-office, big-sur

Current setup

- macOS Big Sur 11.6.1
- Microsoft Outlook for Mac 16.54 (for work, part of office 365 subscription) with New Outlook turned on
- Mail account - an Office 365 account

The issue
In outlook, I select a message and hit <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> to move the selected email(s) to a folder.  The Move screen takes several (4-5) seconds to show.  I then type a folder name into search and there is a 1-2 second lag.  This just started to happen recently (after the 11.6.1 update?, possibly after an Outlook update?)

Everything else works as expected.

Is there a cache file somewhere I can clean-up/clear out that might help this?

Everything I see for support relates to Outlook being slow on Windows (which isn't any help)

---

It would seem 16.55 (21111400) fixed this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft pushed an updated for Outlook today (11/17/2021) that solved this issue for me.